# Too many open files with libevent's evhttp based server

Tags: sockets, libevent

I've created simple evhttp based server.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <event.h>
#include <evhttp.h>

void
handler(struct evhttp_request *req, void *arg) {
  struct evbuffer *buf;
  buf = evbuffer_new();

  if(buf == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Failed to create response buffer\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  evbuffer_add_printf(buf, "Server called");
  evhttp_send_reply(req, HTTP_OK, "OK", buf);
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv) {
  struct evhttp *http;

  event_init();
  http = evhttp_start("0.0.0.0", 8081);

  evhttp_set_gencb(http, handler, NULL);

  event_dispatch();
  evhttp_free(http);

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

When I started benchmarking it using

```
ab -r -n 1000 -c 50 http://0.0.0.0:8081/
```

I'm getting these warnings after some number of tries:

```
[warn] Error from accept() call: Too many open files
```

It's kinda I'm no closing sockets... The concurrency level 50 aims that only 50 sockets will by used a time, right?

Am I supposed to close the socket in the handler function?

Comment: I guess if it is "evbuffer_free(but)"

Answer (score 1):

What is the ulimit set to  open file descriptors? Eg. try with executing 'ulimit -n' command (without quote).  These are the number of file descriptors allowed to be opened in your application.  To increase you can use ulimit command. e.g
ulimit -n 10240

Comment: I've had unlimited number of descriptors set so this wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I started using `event2/*` libs and added `evbuffer_free(buf)` on end of the handler function and it did the job.